# Laplace transform $e^1$

Tags: laplace-transform, integral-transforms

Sorry if this question seems a little easy to solve, just need a little guidance.
So I have to find the Laplace transform of $e^{-2t+1}$. So I separated the exponential to $e^{-2t} + e^1$. Is the Laplace transform of $e^1 = e/s$ since it is just a constant?

Comment: $e^{-2t+1} \ne e^{-2t} + e^1$

Comment: Oops my bad wasn't thinking, how would you suggest starting this question.

Comment: And $\mathcal L (\alpha f +\beta g) = \alpha \mathcal L  f+ \beta \mathcal L g$, where $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb C$.

Comment: @DHMO I believe they're making a new domain where you can do that.  
Consider exponentiation in $\mathbb C$ for example.  It would be ripe for re-formulating rules for exponentiation.

Comment: @user426307:  Perhaps the transform for e^1 is e/0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, $e^{-2t + 1} = e^{-2t}e $

Then, the Laplace transformation :

$\mathcal{L}[e^{-2t + 1}] = \mathcal{L} [e^{-2t}e] = e\mathcal{L} [e^{-2t}] = \frac{e}{s+2}$ by the known Laplace transformation formulas.

Otherwise, just take the integral : $\mathcal{L}\left\lbrace e^{-2t+1}\right\rbrace = e\int_0^\infty e^{-t(2+s)}\,dt = {e\over 2+s}$

Comment: This is false, $L(ab)\ne L(a)L(b)$ if so you would get ${1\over s(2+s)}$

Comment: Sorry, misspell ^^, wanted to product the constant e but was in a hurry writing, fixed now, thanks @AdamHughes !

Comment: Welp, that was easy. Sorry I'm just not used to using e as a constant.

Answer (score 5):

Recall $e^{a+b}=e^a e^b$. Using linearity of an integral transform you see

> $$\mathcal{L}\left\lbrace e^{-2t+1}\right\rbrace = e\int_0^\infty e^{-t(2+s)}\,dt = {e\over 2+s}$$